# Creating files (pdf, xls) with a python script inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker

Trying to create simple files with a python script called "scriptfile.py". When I run it, it outputs a pdf with a sine wave and an xls file containing a 3x10 dataframe that was initially imported from a csv file called "csv_file.csv". In addition, the sine wave plot is shown. This all works fine.

Now I've created a Dockerfile, based on the app.py example in the Docker documentation. I build an image using

```
sudo docker build --tag=testrun .
```

and run it using

```
sudo docker run -p 4000:80 testrun
```

The console output is normal, but no files are created and no plot displayed. The code of the Dockerfile and the scriptfile.py are given below.

It reads

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ADD scriptfile.py /

RUN pip install matplotlib
RUN pip install xlwt
RUN pip install pandas

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME DockerTester

CMD ["python","/scriptfile.py"]
```

The scriptfile.py reads

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv', sep=",", header=None)
df.to_excel(r'xlx_file.xls')

print("plotting ...")

sinusoid=[]
for i in range(100):
    sinusoid.append(math.sin(i))

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(sinusoid)
plt.show()
f.savefig("sin.pdf")
plt.close()

print("... success")
```

Question: Where are the files?

Comment: Don't use `ADD` for normal files like `.py`. If you find yourself changing your `scriptfile.py` often (more often than changing your `pip install` commands) then it would benefit you to place your `COPY` and `WORKDIR` lines after the `RUN pip install`s. That way you don't have to re install with `pip` on every change to your `scriptfile.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, here are some.

## Using `docker cp`

First figure out your containerid by using `docker ps -a`, then do:

```
docker cp <containerid>:/app /tmp/mydir
```

You will find the content on your host at `/tmp/mydir`.

## Using `Dockerfile VOLUME`

Add this line to your `Dockerfile` after your `COPY`:

```
VOLUME /app
```

Now run your container like you are:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 testrun
```

Now do:

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' <containerid>
```

Where `<containerid>` is obtained from `docker ps -a`. You will see something like:

```
[{volume 511961d95cd5de9a32afe3358c7b9af3eabd50179846fdebd9c882d50c7ffee7 /var/lib/docker/volumes/511961d95cd5de9a32afe3358c7b9af3eabd50179846fdebd9c882d50c7ffee7/_data /app local  true }]
```

As you can see there is a path:

> /var/lib/docker/volumes/511961d95cd5de9a32afe3358c7b9af3eabd50179846fdebd9c882d50c7ffee7/_data

That is where the container's `/app` directory contents are located.

## Using `docker run -v`

Change your python script to write a location other than `/app`, something like `f.savefig("/tmp/sin.pdf")`.

Then run docker like this:

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/share/:/tmp -p 4000:80 testrun
```

Now you will find your file on your host at `/tmp/share/`